# Fresh install + a few installs using 45GiB Space?

Tags: 14.04

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I ran all of the updates and then went through added a few choice programs. So far I have added the following....
Skype - For Linux
Gimp
Blender
Wine
PlayonLinux
Steam (No games downloaded, just steam client)

With those programs I added the required registries and a few other odds and ends that those programs require to run on a 64bit system.
So then I added Gparted and wanted to see where I was at for space out of curiousness. I did a custom install 128GB solid state that holds only my boot, / and slash is using just under 8gig but the 3tb drive I put my /Home on is at 45 GIB!!!!!

Maybe its just me but this does NOT seem right. I started with a 100% wipe, all free space available, fresh reformat and without me adding any pics, docs, videos, nothing, absolutely nothing.

I am a noob when it comes to linux and know buttkis so.... any and all help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: can you run `df -h` and show the output?

Comment: How big is /home. System auto allocates 5% for superuser to prevent filling drive. With new very large drives the 5% can be way too much. See man tune2fs and -m for reserved percentage.

Comment: @oldfred My /home is 3Tb and if you look at the #1 answer below I added a screenshot of baobab and Gparted on there.  Let me know if I need to pull anything up so we can be sure everything is in order. I am fairly new to linux so I just want to make sure i am on the right track and no issues.

Answer (score 2):

Here a small list of tools you can use to see disk usage

**Graphical Userinterface**

- baobab

[image]

> Disk Usage Analyzer (aka baobab) is a graphical, menu-driven
>   application to analyse disk usage in a GNOME environment. It can
>   easily scan either the whole filesystem tree, or a specific
>   user-requested directory branch (local or remote).
>
> It also auto-detects in real-time any changes made to your home
>   directory as far as any mounted/unmounted device. Disk Usage Analyzer
>   also provides a full graphical treemap window for each selected
>   folder.

**Terminal**

- ncdu
- df
- du

`baobab` should be a good helper for beginners to visualize the disk your home folder

45GB sounds way to much for a clean install, but i cant judge on your home folder and whatever you placed there

Comment: First off, thank you very much for responding to my post, I pulled it up and made a screen shot, I have baobab right beside gparted, in baobab it shows exactly what I would expect to see. In Gparted, I think it is on something crazy but I am just going to go with it and trust it is right. 

   http://imgur.com/SR9njlX

Comment: maybe use something out of the terminal-tools list above to validate the results. could be there is just a bug in the gparted version you are using (as example)

Comment: Just tested gparted 0.25.0 here on my fedora box and it reports valid values for me & my setup